# how to build (custom) stats for post views, per month

Tags: post-meta, transient, statistics

Does anyone know how I could code something to get the most viewed posts per month (without Jetpack), ideally without having to create a new DB table ?

Maybe there is a smart way to achieve this only using post metas and/or transients.

For the moment, [i'm storing an array of stat entries](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/189989/70449) as a post meta, containing a timestamp. 
Each time the meta is updated, I delete the timestamps < 1 month.
It works, but i'm not sure that it is a good solution.

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: Hey gordie, a little bit broad your request. Do you have already started to set up anything yourself? If yes, please share your findings. If no, what answer exactly are you looking for? Please update your question for clarification. Thank you

Comment: @leymannx: ok, I edited the question with my current workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I'd build that upon and already existing plugin that does the counting for me. I have made quite good experience with [Post Views Counter](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-views-counter/) as it also lets you use it in `WP_Query`. But [WP-PostViews](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-postviews/) looks promising as well. Choose one.

Next I'd query posts by view count from a WordPress cron event that runs monthly. And I'd simply save/add the results in an Options API option as array like `$data[INTEGER_YEAR][INTEGER_MONTH][INTEGER_POST_ID][INTEGER_VIEW_COUNT]`. And pull that off whenever I need it for displaying the high score in a widget or where ever.

Comment: Post Views Counter seems perfect ! Thanks.

Comment: @gordie - Only thing to note about Post Views Counter, it currently doesn't let you set the view count manually (maybe necessary during development) via a meta box, but in post quick edit only instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can track posts views with these functions. Create a new file and call it into your `functions.php`

after you collect enough data, you can create a meta box for Dashboard and you can use a chart module to view post views monthly/yearly etc.

```php
add_action( 'wp_head', 'get_post_id' );
function get_post_id() {
    $postID = get_the_ID();
    return $postID;
}

function getPostViews() {
    $postID    = get_post_id();
    $count_key = 'views';
    $count     = get_post_meta( $postID, $count_key, true );
    if ( $count == '' ) {
        delete_post_meta( $postID, $count_key );
        add_post_meta( $postID, $count_key, '0' );
        return __( '0', 'sagive' );
    }
    return number_format( $count, '0', ',', '.' ) . __( '', 'sagive' );
}


remove_action( 'wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head', 10, 0 );
add_action( 'wp_head', 'setPostViews' );
function setPostViews() {
    if ( ! is_home() && ! is_robots() && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $postID    = get_post_id();
        $count_key = 'views';
        $count     = get_post_meta( $postID, $count_key, true );
        if ( $count == '' ) {
            $count = 0;
            delete_post_meta( $postID, $count_key );
            add_post_meta( $postID, $count_key, '0' );
        } else {
            $count++;
            update_post_meta( $postID, $count_key, $count );
        }
    }
}
```